# How to add regular expression in Excel 2013 tor replace numbers and hashes with comma

Tags: regex, excel

My one of my Excel columns has more than 1000 rows records and it has records like blow

```
Yuichiro Sakai;#75;#Daniel Hinchcliff;#141;#Ali Reza Ehsani;#74
```

and another column like this:

```
Irene Bernabeu;#147;#Aferdita Mekuli;#139
```

the names comes from a database.

What I want is: How can I add a regular expression in Excel 2013 to replace substrings like `;#147;#` and `;#74` with a comma?

Comment: Why you want to replace these two `;#147;# and ;#74 ` only?

Comment: No my dear I want all the different numbers there might be ;#345;# or many other numbers I wanted how to use regular expression in excel to over come this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a great regular expression add-on for Excel it worked great
here is the link for http://www.codedawn.com/

you can use it to add regular expression in excel and solve your problem very easily

many thanks to this add-on: http://www.codedawn.com/

Answer (score 1):

The Excel search and replace does not support regex, but you can use place holders in your search.

Tested in Excel2010:

Search for

```
;#*;#
```

and replace with

```
,
```

for the pattern without closing ";#" you have to do a second search.

Comment: Thanks your approach is also useful

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern

```
(?>;#\d*)+
```

and replace with `,`  [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/34)